# SSH Hostname not found

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

Can anyone explain this behavior? I am trying to SSH to my raspberry pi, and get Could not resolve hostname errors. They seem to go away when I cd to my home directory. What is even stranger is I started in my home directory using cd ~

```
sstan@STEVEN-PC ~
$ ssh pi@raspberrypi
ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi: Name or service not known

sstan@STEVEN-PC ~
$ cd ~

sstan@STEVEN-PC ~
$ ssh pi@raspberrypi
ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi: Name or service not known

sstan@STEVEN-PC ~
$ cd /home/sstan/

sstan@STEVEN-PC ~
$ ssh pi@raspberrypi
Linux raspberrypi 4.1.19-v7+ #858 SMP Tue Mar 15 15:56:00 GMT 2016 armv7l
```

Comment: Please repeat the process but this time, after the initial failure, wait five minutes instead of changing directory and then try the `ssh` again.

Comment: There was no recent reboot, and it had happened several times. I had a feeling it might have just been my local DNS struggling, but figured I would ask if this was known by anyone else

Comment: Did you try ssh pi@raspberrypi.local